# I'm trying to recover images from a memory card, but most of the images I'm getting are corrupted. Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Tags: c, cs50, recovery

```
while( !feof(card))
{
  FILE *f1=fopen(gp[i],"a");                            //Opens a new file to store the bytes in
  fread(buffer1, sizeof(BYTE), 512, card);              //Reads a set of bytes from the card
  if (buffer1[0] == 0xff && buffer1[1] == 0xd8 && buffer1[2] == 0xff && buffer1[3]/0x10==0x0e)  //Checks whether the first 4 bytes match the start of a jpg
  {

      fwrite(buffer1, sizeof(BYTE), 512, f1);               //Writes the bytes on to the opened file
      fread(buffer1, sizeof(BYTE), 512, card);              //Reads the next set of bytes from the card

      while (buffer1[0] != 0xff && buffer1[1] != 0xd8 && buffer1[2] != 0xff && buffer1[3]/0x10!=0x0e)   //Repeats the below process till we find the start of a new jpg
      {
      fwrite(buffer1, sizeof(BYTE), 512, f1);               //Writes the bytes on to the opened file
      fread(buffer1, sizeof(BYTE), 512, card);              //Reads the next set of bytes from the card
      }
      fclose(f1);
      i++;
  }
```

Comment: You should read: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: I changed it to while j<50 and modified it to read only 50 images. It's still not working

Comment: How is `buffer1` defined and initialised?

Comment: Also, does the real code lack all error checking?

Comment: At least one problem is the second while condition. See [this answer](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/28538/pset4-recover-recovers-49-images-but-not-last-image-and-also-doesnt-pass-chec/28542#28542) for full explanation.

Comment: buffer1 is defined as an array of 512 BYTEs

Comment: Sorry there's no error checking, I'm still a beginner

Comment: Being a beginner is no excuse for not doing error checking. Error checking is not something annoying but it will help you detect problems in your code early.

Comment: I don't know how to do error checking. If you could tell me a good place to learn how to do error checking I will try it

Comment: @DinethHettiarachchi read the documentation of `fopen` and especially about what happens if the file you try to open cannot be opened, for example because it does not exist.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus I altered the while condition as pointed out but now I'm getting only 1 jpg and that's not being opened either

Comment: @Jabberwocky fopen is supposed to give me a pointer to a file right?

Comment: @DinethHettiarachchi exactly, but what does it "give to you" if the file __does not exist__? It's written in the documentation.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm supposed to get a null pointer and apparently a global variable errno is set to indicate the error. I don't understand what's happening there. I feel like I'm missing something

Comment: @DinethHettiarachchi roughly like this: if `fopen` returns NULL, then print an error message and abort, otherwise proceed. This is most basic programming knowledge.

Comment: @Jabberwocky my program compiles though and doesn't print out error messages